# Macro to automatically output values to different cells by date

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first time in the SO forums and i need help with a bit of a problem i have. I am trying to code a macro with VBA for excel that retrieves some values from two tables inserted to a worksheet which dynamically update with access.

Im not sure if i am explaining myself well up to the moment.

I want a macro that will compare the value of cell A1 (this cell is the date today) with the values of different column headers within a row. If the date is the same as the one in the column header I would like it to execute this calculatiom:

=SUM(Modelos!V3:V31)

At first i thought about using and If function to check if the A1 was the same as the column header, but then i remembered that when the date changes the value will turn 0 and i want it to keep it old value.

I there a way for me to make the cell keep its ald value instead of turning 0?

Update (17/10/13)
I then thought about using many if functions to hold the values but this didnt work, i add a photo of what i have tried
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9XQY.png

Comment: How are you triggering your macro? Button, event?

Comment: @PortlandRunner i would like to trigger it with a button that is visible for the user

Comment: @pnuts the thing is that i need it to update daily

Comment: @pnuts okay, i was certain that i was going to confuse you with my explanation. what i want is to get the current value for =SUM(Modelos!V3:V31) and put it into a cell, the value of =SUM(Modelos!V3:V31) will change constantly so i want it to have different record to use them later on a cash flow

Answer (score 0):

You could use an easy `if` statement in your VBA code:
Edit: according to your different comments, screenshots and edits, here is my understanding of your needs:

```
Dim Row As Integer, Column As Integer, vSum As Integer, i As Integer
    If Cells(Row, Column) = Cells(1, 1) Then
        Sheets("Modelos").Activate
        vSum = 0
        For i = 3 To 31
            vSum = vSum + Cells(i, 22)
        Next
        Sheets("Sales Flash").Activate
        Cells(Row + 3, Column) = vSum
    End If 'no else: if the value is different, the cell content will remain untouched
```

Formulas are definitely not an option there, either directly in your sheet or VBA because your content will be systematically updated with the new values in your Modelos sheet.

Comment: The thing is that i need it to check a range of cells, for example from B4 to G4. If D4 is equal to that A1, then i want the value to appear on D5.

Comment: Then you can use a `for` loop before your `if` statement, and offset `Row` and `Column` accordingly.

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont undertand what you are telling me, ive got no clue about VBA and excel

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Excel sheet, with explanations of which columns you want to check, and which cells/columns you want to update?

Comment: Okay, here you have the screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/qktu8HN.png if B6 is the same as the date, i want it to copy the values of this table http://i.imgur.com/YNadho9.png the ones for "Volume Of Sales" "Revenue" and "Profit" which can be in cells U1,V1,W1 respectively

Comment: I think what you need is a bit clearer now. I hope I am not wrong.

Comment: So, can you provide me a code or at least an idea of what i could do to make my system work

Comment: @Sylvian i get an eror with this line of the code `If Cells(Row, Column) = Cells(1, 1) Then`

Comment: Yes, you have to initialize your variables, sorry. The question is, do you want to place the formula in a specific cell (ie, will always be the same), or do you want to scan a range of rows and/or columns?